# Multible languages in the same page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-intl

I have pages with multible languages English/Arabic for instance when using typography. fontFamily property it applies the same font for both languages is there a good/easy way to apply different fonts depending on elements language i don't have much experience in this any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Just add a `.font-class` in the css file or I don't get your question

Comment: thank you @nazimboudeffa for the quick response I'm using jss with material ui there is no css file

Comment: You're welcome, if it's this framework https://cssinjs.org I guess there's no problem to use a class element and afect it a font style, I know what is material ui but it doesn't matter

Comment: You are correct, to make it clear your suggestion is to have a class with the font style attribute and apply it to every other language element ?

i think if that so it will be very hard because i'm using react-intl to change some elements content depending on the user selected language

i was hoping for something that allows the browser to choose between fonts for the element content